# Onclick event refuses to work, what's wrong with it, and how to I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on setting up a validation form. What I'm trying to do currently is get the button to call my function, and which will then validate some fields, and either prompt, or display an error message.

I have tried moving the position of the script tag, I've tried changing the position of the script tags, and I've tried debugging it to see where it is going wrong. None of which has worked, I am completely dumbfounded.

Also, I've tested on Google Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, same results.

```js
var emailAdd = document.getElementById("emailAdd");
var error = document.getElementById("error");

function checkValidity() {

  if (emailAdd.value.length === 0 || !RegExp.test(emailAdd.value)) {
    error.className = "error-message"

  } else {
    prompt("t");
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  resize: none;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #FDD;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px #FF0000;
}

input:focus.invalid {
  outline: none;
}

span.error-message {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" class="emailAdd" id="emailAdd" placeholder="Eg. johnsmith@account.com" onkeyup="emailValidate();">
<span class="error-message" id="error">test</span>

<button type="button" onclick="checkValidity();">Submit</button>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ev95wz1d/3/ (Has CSS, and everything)
Edit: JsFiddle has class set as error-message, which shows my desired outcome, change it back to error to see the problem.

If the if statement is true, it sound display the error message (I am aware there is no text, but the span should still change classes, and will appear without text), when the statement is false, prompt a message.

However, it does nothing. No error messages, nothing.

Comment: You haven't properly selected the input element. emailAdd is undefined in your code when it executes.

Comment: @daddygames omitted from the jsfiddle, and script, but it is declared. I'll add that to the jsfiddle to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please include a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ***in the body of your question*** - external links have a tendency to break and nuke value for future visitors to this question.

Comment: You have not taken any references of the DOM nodes in your script.

Comment: @esqew the new way the questions are setup made it impossible to format it, I'll add it now.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how jsfiddle handles the javascript, but I have been unable to get the button to work there also. I removed all other HTML and only click for button and it only works when the code is written inline inside the HTML. It's like JSFiddle isn't recognizing the function... ?

Comment: Your fiddle *does* give an error.  Open your browser's devtools.

Comment: jsfiddle is set up wrong. function is declared inside on onload and will not be global.

Comment: @daddygames That's the problem I'm having. It literally will not work, and I have absolutely no clue why. I've tested in different browsers, debugging, nearly everything I can think of, and no luck. I'm completely dumbfounded.

Comment: @MarsBARRanger From the devtools console: `(index):84 Uncaught ReferenceError: emailValidate is not defined`, and indeed, there is no `emailValidate` in your JS.

Comment: @Amy Another function I've omitted. Will add now. EDIT: Updated.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is your function name `checkValidity`. Change it to something else and it works. `checkValidity` is an existing function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

Comment: @imvain2 Wow, I think that’s it. I’ll give it a try, and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fighting using the old way of handling events, using the new method of `addEventListener` does work.

Looks like `checkValidity` is an existing function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) so yours is competing with it. You can either use `addEventListener` or change the name of your function.

```js
var emailAdd = document.getElementById("emailAdd");
var error = document.getElementById("error");

emailAdd.addEventListener("input",function(){
    if(this.value.length === 0 || !RegExp.test(this.value)){
        this.className = "invalid";
    }
    else{
        this.className = "valid";
    }
});

document.getElementById("btn-submit").addEventListener("click",function(){
  if(emailAdd.value.length === 0 || !RegExp.test(emailAdd.value)){
      error.className = "error-message"
      error.innerHTML = "ERROR";
    }
    else{
        prompt("t");
    }
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    resize: none;
}

input.invalid {
    background-color: #FDD;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px #FF0000;
}

input:focus.invalid {
    outline: none;
}

span.error-message {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" class="emailAdd" id="emailAdd" placeholder="Eg. johnsmith@account.com">
<span class="error-message" id="error">test</span>

<button type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This does work, I'm really confused why the way I have it setup is not working. It seems perfectly valid, yet it honestly just refuses to work.

Comment: @MarsBARRanger, I updated my answer and added a comment to your question. The problem is `checkValidity` is a function already and yours is competing with it. If you simply rename your function it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your `RegExp` class, but I think you want to achieve this (minus the regex checking):

```js
var emailAdd = document.getElementById("emailAdd");
var error = document.getElementById("error");

function emailValidate() {
  if(emailAdd.value.length === 0){ // Removed regex checking for now
        error.className = "error-message"

    }
    else{
        error.className = "good-message"
    }
}

function submit() {
  if(emailAdd.value.length === 0){ // Removed regex checking for now
        confirm("Bad!")
    }
    else{
        confirm("Good!")
    }
}

// Use event listeners for easier handling
document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  submit();
});

document.getElementById("emailAdd").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  emailValidate();
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    resize: none;
}

input.invalid {
    background-color: #FDD;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px #FF0000;
}

input:focus.invalid {
    outline: none;
}

/*A new class for positive validation*/
span.good-message {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

span.error-message {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" class="emailAdd" id="emailAdd" placeholder="Eg. johnsmith@account.com">
<span class="good-message" id="error">test</span> <!-- Initial validation should be positive: hence the class good-message -->

<button id="b1">Submit</button>
```

Feel free to add in your `RegExp` validation again!